# Border not getting applied to full view

Tags: ios, uiview, border, cashapelayer

I am setting up the dashed border to my UIView it is getting applied in iPhone 6,7,8. But if open in iPhone XR it is coming like this.

My view is named as camerauiview

The border I am setting up in this function by calling it in viewdidload().

```
func setupBorder(){
    let dashedborder = CAShapeLayer()
    dashedborder.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4076032743, green: 0.1454663677, blue: 0.9795397903, alpha: 1)
    dashedborder.lineWidth = 2
    dashedborder.lineDashPattern = [7 , 7]
    dashedborder.frame = camerauiview.bounds
    dashedborder.fillColor = nil
    dashedborder.path = UIBezierPath(rect: camerauiview.bounds).cgPath
    camerauiview.layer.addSublayer(dashedborder)
}
```

This is coming like this.
[image]

For reference, I have given background color as grey just to showcase how much area it is covering.

Comment: check your camerauiview.bounds i think may be there is difference between camerauiview frame and bounds.

Comment: Can you please explain your comment?

Comment: try to print you camerauiview.bounds and  camerauiview.frame

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` your view constraint not loaded. So, you have to try in `viewDidAppear` or apply layer with `delay` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `func viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this method. However, this method being called does not indicate that the individual layouts of the view's subviews have been adjusted. Each subview is responsible for adjusting its own layout.

Your view controller can override this method to make changes after the view lays out its subviews. The default implementation of this method does nothing.

Use your `func setupBorder()` in override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() Method like:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        setupBorder()
    }
```